# blender 2.8 sculpt mode display

Tags: sculpt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMCw8.jpg)Hope someone can help. When in blender 2.8 sculpt mode the color of my object changes. Look like mocap from 2.79, except I have'[image]nt enabled the mocap in preferences. Also when I tqab into edit or object from sculpt the display stays the same as it was in sculpt mode. and I getno grid displayed either.
I did'nt change anything from the original download.
I have included some screenshots. I am pretty sure I hit something but I have tried everything I can think of. checked under materials nothing uninstalled then reinstalled,

[image]

Comment: This is the intended functionality. If you would like the grid back, you can re-add it in the overlays menu, it is just turned off by default in the sculpting workspace.

Comment: you can get the grid back, by clicking on the overlays dropdown, and checking **floor**